# Why are not all the Leaflet markers being displayed on the map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

This code looks good to me. The data comes back correct, marker objects are being created, but only the first marker is displayed. There are actually two sets of markers, the set in question is all red markers. I've commented out the others but left the code.
Here is the code created by MySQL/PHP:

```
var W0KCN3 = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(39.2859182,-94.667236),{
                        contextmenu: true, contextmenuWidth: 140,
                        contextmenuItems: [{ text: 'Click here to add mileage circles',
                            callback: circleKoords}],
                        icon: new L.NumberedRedIcon({number: 'E1' }),
                        title: "marker_E1"}).addTo(fg).bindPopup("W0KCN-3 Platte Co. Resource Center<br>Kansas City, MO<br>39.2859182, -94.667236<br>EM29PG").openPopup();

                        $(EOC._icon).addClass("redmrkr");
                        markers.push(W0KCN3);


                var W0KCN4 = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(39.3721733,-94.780929),{
                        contextmenu: true, contextmenuWidth: 140,
                        contextmenuItems: [{ text: 'Click here to add mileage circles',
                            callback: circleKoords}],
                        icon: new L.NumberedRedIcon({number: 'E2' }),
                        title: "marker_E2"}).addTo(fg).bindPopup("W0KCN-4 Platte Co. EOC<br>Platte City, MO<br>39.3721733, -94.780929<br>EM29OI").openPopup();

                        $(EOC._icon).addClass("redmrkr");
                        markers.push(W0KCN4);


                var STJOMC = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(38.93620,-094.60370),{
                        contextmenu: true, contextmenuWidth: 140,
                        contextmenuItems: [{ text: 'Click here to add mileage circles',
                            callback: circleKoords}],
                        icon: new L.NumberedRedIcon({number: 'H1' }),
                        title: "marker_H1"}).addTo(fg).bindPopup(" Saint Joseph Medical Center<br>Kansas City, MO 64114-4865<br>38.93620, -094.60370<br>EM28QW").openPopup();

                        $(Hospital._icon).addClass("redmrkr");
                        markers.push(STJOMC);
```

In this simple case, marker W0KCN3 appears on the map but no subsequent markers are displayed. It appears to me the server returns all the information correctly, there are about 70 more markers. If I comment out the MySQL call for W0KCN3 then marker W0KCN4 shows up and no others. This holds true for at least the first 10, which I tried.

This test program can be seen at https://net-control.us/map1Rose.php

Comment: Sounds like some error in your JS is raising an exception and halting execution of any further JS. Are there any errors on your browser's console?

Comment: I get one error in Developer Tools. Uncaught ReferenceError: EOC is not defined, but I can't locate the reference to EOC in the code. But that does give me an idea that I'll explore.

Comment: Solved: The issue was building the marker addClass. I had to enclose the $row[class]  to include quotes. I'm not sure why they were not required in previous versions of my code but they are now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to include quotes around the $row[class] in the following;

```
$(\"$row[class]\"._icon).addClass(\"redmrkr\");
```

Previously this worked without the quotes, I can't explain why. But adding them allowed all the markers to be displayed.

Comment: Or you could use https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#icon-classname instead.